# Blocked a specific email in Squarespace using Code injection JS but I still get email from specific spammer

Tags: spam-prevention, squarespace

I added a code injection in Squarespace to block specific email. If user inputs email, submit button will be disabled. I added recaptcha before and didn't work so I decided to block the specific email. But I still get same spam email from same email used in my contact form. Is there any other way to fix this?

I get the same experience posted here: https://www.signal-arnaques.com/en/scam/view/260546

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible explanation is that the submit button is not being used to submit the form (it could be submitted programmatically or by other means). You could use JavaScript to add an event listener to the 'submit' event and, within that, prevent the form from being submitted based on your comparison logic. It'd look something like:

```
var myForm = /* Get the form element. */;
myForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  var emailAddress = /* Get the value of the field */;
  if (emailAddress == "info@domainworld.com") {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Of course, because it's client-side JavaScript, it's entirely possible that the bot could work around this as well.